# How to find the same number in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var text = "Andorras tourism services an estimated 10.2 million visitors annually.[1] 
It has been a member of the United Nations since 1993.[2] 
In the world at 81 years, according to The Lancet.[3]

[1]HOTELERIA I TURISME. Retrieved 14 May 2015.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14."
```

How to find numbers every sign `[ ]`. And if detected there are numbers inside the sign `[ ]` and the same number like this "`annually.[1] ...... [1]HOTELERIA`". So give `<span class="bignote">` on the first number, and `<span class="smallnote">` on the second number

But if there is only one number inside the `[]` sign. Or there are more than two same number inside the `[]` sign, it is undetectable

Output like this, only [1] only gets the span code

```
Andorras tourism services an estimated 10.2 million visitors annually.<span class="bignote">[1]</span>
It has been a member of the United Nations since 1993.[2] 
In the world at 81 years, according to The Lancet.[3]

<span class="smallnote">[1]</span>HOTELERIA I TURISME. Retrieved 14 May 2015.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
```

**Update :**

`[2]` can not be bignote and smallnote because `[2]` there are more than two, when viewed from the contents of the text, there are four signs `[2]`

`[3]` can not be a bignote and smallnote because `[3]` there is only one

```js
var text = "Andorras tourism services an estimated 10.2 million visitors annually.[1]<br>It has been a member of the United Nations since 1993.[2]<br>In the world at 81 years, according to The Lancet.[3]<br><br><br><br>Note: <br>[1]HOTELERIA I TURISME. Retrieved 14 May 2015. <br>[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14. <br>[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14. <br>[2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14."

$("#text").html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
</div>
```

**Update Louys Patrice Bessette**

If you see this https://jsfiddle.net/bobha9gc/

What if when I enter `[1]` in **textarea content**, then **textarea note** will automatically add contents `[1]`. But if I delete it in **textarea content**. The **textarea note** will also be deleted

`[1]` in content to be `<sup id="1">[1]</sup>` and `[1]` in note to be `<span id="1">[1]</span>` in RESULT

And this is no limitation like my previous question. If there are `[1] [1]` more than one in **content**, it is inserted into the note

And lastly, how to detect if the textarea notes have not been filled. 
If I do not fill part `[4]` then it can not be sent, or bring up `alert()`

Comment: Where is that text coming from?... I mean, where do you take it? It has to be inputed into a script...

Comment: Please provide the original HTML, and also explain why [2] didn't get bignote/smallnote

Comment: `[2]` can not be bignote and smallnote because `[2]` there are more than two, when viewed from the contents of the text, there are four signs `[2]`
 And `[3]` can not be a bignote and smallnote because `[3]` there is only one

Comment: Your `text` variable actually is invalid... There is `"` in the text... And you just can't define a variable on multi lines like this. So again, the source of this text would be usefull.

Comment: I have omitted it, i took it on wikipedia

Comment: I don't care the source where you took the text itself... But where could a script take it. In your WordPress page, maybe?

Comment: What did you actually try? nothing? Why not regular expressions to retrieve the [...whatever...] ?

Comment: In my HTML not WordPress

Comment: So why don't you post your HTML then?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/krkfdfup/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you were aware of the complexity of your question.

Next time, when you are asked for your HTML or any other info about your code, post it.
You'll not always fall on a patient person like me.

That said... I would NEVER cut and paste a whole text in a JS variable like you do. I would use it in my HTML, like in the example below, and then, run a script on the relevant parts.

That is a "coding best practice", if I can say... And it avoids issues with problematic characters like double quotes `"`.

---

**Now, the script...**
You need to find particular string of numbers between square brackets.
[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be used to find them.

Then, you need to check if a found number:

1. is in the text part AND in the notes part.
2. isn't in the notes part more than once.

And you have to add a `span` element around it with a class if it is in the text **or** with another class if it is in the notes.

You agree that it isn't simple...
And I'm sure you would like the script to work with many different text and note chunks.

> ...more than two same number inside the [] sign, it is undetectable.

The way I made it, it works with numbers having more than one digit, as opposed to your assumption.

I used `for` loops, and methods like [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)...
And I applyed them on the text splitted in two part, main text and notes.

I assumed that the same number can appear more than once in the main text.

Have a look at the below snippet or the [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zdjqRo?editors=1111).
The code is well commented.

```js
var spans = [];

// The pattern to look for.
var pattern = /\[\d+\]/gm;

// The two HTML text chunks to work on.
var text = $(".text").html();
var notes = $(".notes").html();

// Two arrays of text matching the pattern.
var match_text = text.match(pattern);
var match_notes = notes.match(pattern);

// Some console logs.
console.log( JSON.stringify(match_text) );
console.log( JSON.stringify(match_notes) );

// Choose the longuest for the comparison loop.
var longer_array = match_text;
var shorter_array = match_notes;
if(match_text.length < match_notes){
  text_longer = match_notes;
  shorter_array = match_text;
  console.log("Less matches in text.");
}

// Comparison loop.
for(i=0;i<longer_array.length;i++){
  if( shorter_array.indexOf(longer_array[i]) != -1){
    console.log(longer_array[i]+" FOUND IN BOTH ARRAYS.");
    
    // An inner loop to check if the text found occurs more than once in notes.
    var notes_occurance = 0;
    for(j=0;j<match_notes.length;j++){
    
      if( longer_array[i] == match_notes[j] ){
        notes_occurance++;
      }
    }
    
    // If there is only one occurance, keep that text in the spans array.
    if(notes_occurance == 1){
      spans.push(longer_array[i]);
    }else{
      console.log(longer_array[i]+" is in notes more than once.")
    }
  }
}
// Console log the result.
console.log( JSON.stringify(spans) );

// Now add spans to both text chunks.
for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
  text = text.replace(spans[i], "<span class='bignote'>"+spans[i]+"</span>");
  notes = notes.replace(spans[i], "<span class='smallnote'>"+spans[i]+"</span>");
  
  // Update HTML.
  $(".text").html(text);
  $(".notes").html(notes);
}
```

```css
.bignote{
  background-color: #37EF40;  /* green */
}
.smallnote{
  background-color: #EFE937;  /* yellow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">
  Andorras tourism services an estimated 10.2 million visitors annually.[1]<br>
  It has been a member of the United Nations since 1993.[2]<br>
  In the world at 81 years, according to The Lancet.[3]<br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="notes">
  Note: <br>
  [1]HOTELERIA I TURISME. Retrieved 14 May 2015. <br>
  [2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14. <br>
  [2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14. <br>
  [2]United Nations Member States. Un.org. Retrieved 2015-05-14.
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for that, hmm what if it all joins? If you look at your code, you separate the text and notes. I mean, if the sentence is incorporated. So,  contents of `notes`, into the `text`

Comment: It has to be two strings... If it's only one, you have to find something that is ALWAYS presents to split it in two... Like `Note: <br>`, for example.

Comment: So can not, without a separator?

Comment: No. Because if the script find 2 occurance of `[1]`... How to be sure the second is in notes? Maybe they are both in notes or both in the text.

Comment: How if using :last for small notes?

Comment: It would ensure that the last is in notes either. It may be twice in the text.

Comment: Yes, what if it is like that? Using: last

Comment: It would **not** ensure... I skipped a word in my previous comment. lol Nothing stops you from trying to use `:last` on a single string. Do it. I don't want to lose time on a bad solution.

Comment: Ok, I follow your way, please see my update. I use separator

Comment: I [**updated your Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/68v62qnf/) with the code I suggested two days ago... And very few small changes.